# Qualitative theory of ODE’s restricted to bounded solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Assume that you have an ODE
$$F(t,x(t),…,x^n(t))=0$$,

and you know that there exist some subset on the space on initial conditions such that every solution of the ODE with initial values in this subset yields a bounded orbit.

Is there any qualitative theory for ODE’s applying for the bounded orbits only? For example, that the bounded orbits have some sort of stability that the non-bounded orbits don’t,etc.

Answer (score 0):

In general, bounded orbits are not a stable property, consider e.g $F(x, x') = x—x'$.

Looking for instance at first order autonomous system $x'(t) = F(x(t))$, assuming each orbit is complete and $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then the orbits in a connected component of the open subset $\{F\neq 0\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ all do the same thing: either flow off to infinity (unbounded component) or flow to the left (or right) towards a critical point on the boundary of the connected component (bounded on the left or respectively right). This shows that the non-trivial bounded orbits form an open set (hence stable). But so do the unbounded orbits. The remaining orbits are trivial orbits (the zeros of $F$).

Is this what you had in mind?